# Facing problem using the Ng-Class with spaces

Tags: angular

I have tried running ngclass in my datatable using the badges from bootstrap but the class has spaces in it so the class is not working properly then i got something from the google but still it is not properly applied.
MY Code:

```
<td>
  <div class="badge"
    [ngClass]="{'badge badge-primary': material.submitedStatus=='Open','badge badge-warning': material.submitedStatus=='Region Head Approved'}></div>
</td>
```

[image: this is how it is showing right now but this is not the correct way]

when i inspect the specific tag i can see that the class which is applied at the last does not have the badge icon as the correct class is "badge badge-primary".

```
 <div _ngcontent-rey-c5="" class="badge-primary" ng-reflect-klass="badge" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Open</div>
```

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

Ultimately we want to apply both **badge** and **badge-primary/badge-warning class**

Here is how you can get it working.

```html
<td>
  <div class="badge"
    [ngClass]="{'badge-primary': material.submitedStatus=='Open','badge-warning': material.submitedStatus=='Region Head Approved','badge': material.submitedStatus==('Region Head Approved' || 'Open')}>
    </div>
</td>
```

Let me know if this works out.

Comment: in this case what happens is that the when i put "Region Head Approved" first in the || then on it gets appeared correctly and vice versa for the "Open"

Answer (score 0):

`.badge` is removed because Angular unset classes `.badge` (including `.badge-warning`) when the value of `material.submitedStatus` is `'Region Head Approved'`

You need to name properties `.badge-primary` and `.badge-warning` in `[ngClass]`.

```html
<td>
  <div class="badge"
    [ngClass]="{'badge-primary': material.submitedStatus=='Open','badge-warning': material.submitedStatus=='Region Head Approved'}"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: can't infer that he wants badge class to be applied always to the div. can we?

Comment: @ishansrivastava I thought `class="badge"` means wanting to do that.

Comment: i want to use the badge class always in front beacuse thats the only way it completes the class and i tried using the .badge-primary but its nor working